# How to Make NGINX to use System Proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass, transparent-proxy, mcafee

I am trying to setup a nginx server that forwards the incoming request to a corporate porxy (its a mcafee proxy) with a proxy header Host and the actual destination host something like `proxy_set_header Host xyz.com:443`.

This works perfectly fine for **http** requests but not for **https**

here is my nginx.conf (assuming no proxy auth required)

```
server {
        listen       80;

        location /test/ {
            proxy_pass http://my-corporate-proxy:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host mytargetdomain.com:443;
        }
```

here my expectation is when i hit `http://localhost:80/test/api/health` the request should go to nginx and then to `http://my-corporate-proxy:8080/api/health` with Host header and from my proxy it should initiate a https request like `https://mytargetdomain.com/api/health`.

but this doesnt happening in case of https.

is there any way I can make it work ? or if I make nginx honour system proxy that should also fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use nginx for this. Use a proper forward proxy server.

Comment: thanks Michael for responding. Cant we use nginx as a proper forward proxy? Reason we are restricted to nginx is for some security reasons (restricted by our org). Adding to my original question, can nginx use system proxy ? If yes how ? I knew it doesn't by default. Please advice

Comment: Nginx is a reverse proxy; you're trying to use it as a forward proxy which it was not designed for. It is somewhat possible but you'll keep running into issues most likely.

Answer (score 0):

This setting might work. The proxy setting of OS must allow the nginx service go through. i.e. If Windows Nginx + Proxifier, in the Proxifier menu, [Profile][Advanced][Sevices and other users]...options, must be checked to enable nginx service pass.

```
http{

...  


upstream service_behind_proxy  {
            server my-corporate-service-behind-proxy:8080;
        }

server {
        listen       80;

        location /test/ {
            proxy_pass http://service_behind_proxy;
            proxy_set_header Host mytargetdomain.com:443;
        }

}
```